# @NotNull ignored on class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, bean-validation

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  private String Id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Integer size;

  public void setSize(Integer size) { this.size = size; }
  public Integer getSize() { return this.size; }

  public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
  public String getId() { return this.id; }
}
```

A repository:

```
@Repository
public class MyEntityDAO {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public void create(MyEntity myEntity) {
    em.persist(myEntity);
  }
}
```

A test which should throw an exception:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
public class MyEntityDAOTest {

  @Inject 
  private MyEntityDAO myEntityDAO;

  @Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public void nullSizeNotAllowedTest() {
    MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
    myEntity.setSize(null);
    myEntity.setId("entity_id");
    myEntityDAO.create(myEntity);
  }
}
```

However the Test fails. The Entity does not throw the required exception. The annotation works OK for String, but not for Integer.

The auto-generated table for MyEntity:

```
FIELD   TYPE            NULL    KEY     DEFAULT  
ID      VARCHAR(255)    NO      PRI     NULL
SIZE    INTEGER(10)     NO              NULL
```

<s>**UPDATE**</s>

Everything works when I specify the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = ...)` to the `Id` field. However, I want to be able to assign my own value to Primary Key field.

**UPDATE 2**

Updated Entity (Repository was updated to reflect changes as well):

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  private Long Id;

  @NaturalId
  private String oldId;

  @NotNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Integer size;

  /* getters and setters */
}
```

The auto-generated table for MyEntity:

```
FIELD   TYPE            NULL    KEY     DEFAULT  
ID      BIGINT(19)      NO      PRI     NULL
OLD_ID  VARCHAR(255)    YES     UNI     NULL
SIZE    INTEGER(10)     NO              NULL
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Test fails"? Does it throw another exception?

Comment: No, it does not throw any exception.

Comment: Add the `EntityManager` to your test. Call `flush` after the `myEntityDAO.create`. Also make sure you have the proper `@NotNull` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `entityManager.flush()` after calling `entityManager.save()`.

Otherwise, the exception will not be thrown and will not be picked up in your test.

Here is a full working example:

MyEntity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Integer size;

    public MyEntity(){}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer size) {
         this.size = size;
    }
}
```

MyEntityDAO:

```
@Repository
public class MyEntityDAO {

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManager;

     public void save(MyEntity myEntity){
          entityManager.persist(myEntity);
          entityManager.flush();
     }
}
```

MyEntityDAOTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
public class MyEntityDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityDAO myEntityDAO;

    @Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void nullSizeNotAllowedTest() throws Exception {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        myEntity.setId("testId");
        myEntity.setSize(null);
        myEntityDAO.save(myEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if I am already supplied the value? What if it's a value that can't be generated? For illustration purposes, say I want to register people. During registration I ask them for their national identification number (assume it's unique for every person of the world) - e.i. perfectly valid primary key. How do I proceed now? Do I have to create a new ID field with incrementing values just because?

Comment: I think using a national identification number should work. Simply annotating it with `@Id` should be enough. However, I'm not sure if duplicate detection as well as constraints like "not null" work as well when doing so.
I found a question/answer similar to yours which might be interesting to you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712749/spring-data-jpa-does-not-allow-an-entity-to-be-peristed-if-the-primary-key-is-no

Comment: I handle duplicate detection by querying the DB first before calling `em.persist(obj)`. But why wouldn't the `@NotNull` annotation work on a non-Id field `Integer size`?

Comment: So I read something up on JPA/Hibernate documentation and has added a new automatically generated `Long id` field to the entity and renamed the `String Id` into something else + annotated the String field with `@NaturalId` annotation. The problem however still persists.

Comment: One more think I can think of: Have you made sure that your Java entity matches your actual database entity? E.g. Is the `Id` column marked as a primary key in your database schema?

Comment: I've added the Table description to my question. Yes, the Id field is marked as Primary key, the old_id is marked as unique (@NaturalId) AND disallow NULLs (although the default value is set to Null ???).

Comment: Your Java entity `Id` is a String, yet your schema is of type `BIGINT(19)`. Make sure that they have the exact same type and name. What database are you using?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. The table was adapted to adopt the new Entity scheme I described two comments above. I have updated the question to reflect these changes. I'm using H2 database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Working as expected in my case.

```
@Column(name = "size", nullable = false)
@NotNull(message= "size may not be empty.")
private Integer size;
```

Comment: @RudimentaryJoe, add a message. Check edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. Check my quest for new observations.

Comment: @RudimentaryJoe, Have you tried like this? `@GenericGenerator(name = "string_based_custom_sequence", strategy = 
"com.ie.customid.EmployeeIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "string_based_custom_sequence")`

Comment: Is there no way to assign a primary key value without a generator? I receive the value in HTTP request. I do not have any generator.

Comment: AFAIK you have to make sure that the supplied value is unique if you annotate it with `@Id`. Usually, a generated value is used for IDs. You can even supply your own generator (see my updated answer).